# Pointer-to-function or pointer-to-object. What is the meaning of clang warning?

Tags: c++, c++17, function-pointers, compiler-warnings

Sorry for possible duplicates. Because I couldn't find the answer

So my question is. I am trying to get an address to the function

```
void func() {}

void* funcPtr = func;
```

I am using C++ 17 at Visual Studio and clang giving me that warning

```
implicit conversion between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is a microsoft extension[clang-diagnostic-microsoft-cast]
```

I want to use it, to check if two pointer to a function are actually pointing to the same function. For example:

```
const std::function<void()>& stdFunc1 = func;
const std::function<void()>& stdFunc2 = func;

void* funcAdr1 = *stdFunc1.target<void(*)()>();
void* funcAdr2 = *stdFunc2.target<void(*)()>();

bool test = funcAdr1 == funcAdr2;
```

What clang trying me to tell. And what possible workaround can I do? For my project it is not really necessary. But I want to know it for future.

Comment: You're staring at the answer yourself. The answer to your question lies somewhere in the "`target<void(*)()>`" part. That's what the compiler is barking about.

Comment: See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void). According to the standard, only pointers to objects are guaranteed to be convertible to and from `void*`.

Comment: Data pointer ≠ function pointer.  (Also, ≠ member function pointer.)